# Run SSJS Activity from External System

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, activity

I have a script activity in Marketing Cloud that processes data from a Data Extension. The requirement is to run this script and save the results in a DE every day, not at a specific time/hour, but when something happens every day on an external system. The data that needs to be processed is in Marketing Cloud and the result should remain in Marketing Cloud, only the start of the job should be external.

I tried to find something on google but can't find what I need. Does anyone know how can I run the script from an external system? It's not important if it's REST API, SOAP API or anything else as long as it works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation will be to place your SSJS in a JSON Code Resource. You can create one under Cloud Pages, where you choose *Code Resource* instead of *Landing Page* in the *Add Content* menu:

[image]

Here you can populate all the information about the resource:

[image]

And lastly choose JSON as Code Resource type:

[image]

```javascript
{
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
//check for API key
var apikey = Platform.Request.GetRequestHeader('x-api-key');
if (apikey == "5QZKGDHI70") {
try{
//Do your SSJS Functions Here

//Assign output from your function to *status* variable, and print it in JSON on success:
Write("\"success\": \"" + status + "\"");
} 
catch(error) {
//Print error message in JSON, if something fails
Write("\"error\": \"" + error + "\"");
}
} else {
Write("\"error\": \"Missing or incorrect API key\"");
}
</script>
}
```

Above SSJS will print the status of your function, error if your script fails, and do a basic security check, to see if the header holds the correct API key (so no simple HTTP GET request to the URL will trigger the script).

Alternatively, if you want to keep everything in Automation Studio, I will recommend you [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/automation-studio-activities/trigger-automations-via-api) on triggering automations with API.

Comment: Nice Idea with the Cloud Page. Is there any advantage in using JSON and not JavaScript?

Comment: That's totally up to you, @Alex -  It all depends on how you intend to call the URL. IMHO JSON is most universal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with using REST API then this **undocumented** API may work for you.

```
POST /automation/v1/scripts/{{scriptObjectId}}/start 
Host: {{yourendpoint}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

The easiest way to get the "scriptObjectId" is you click on the Script Activity you want to execute. From your browser, it will look like something like this

```
https://mc.s10.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Automation%20Studio/AutomationStudioFuel3/%23ActivityModal/423/Your-Script-ObjectID
```

The last part after the last slash punctuation is your Script Object Id you need for the API call

[Reference](https://gortonington.com/access-script-activities-via-api/) from Greg's blog.

Comment: I will not recommend relying on *undocumented* APIs in a production environment, as they might be changed or removed with no prior notice.

Comment: @LukasLunow I agree. Thank you for pointing out the risks.